# How to do a newline in output

Tags: ruby, newline

How do I make `\n` actually work in my output? At the moment it just writes it all in 1 long block. Thanks for any help

```
Dir.chdir 'C:/Users/name/Music'
music = Dir['C:/Users/name/Music/*.{mp3, MP3}']
puts 'what would you like to call the playlist?'
@new = ''
playlist_name = gets.chomp + '.m3u'

music.each do |z|
  @new += z + '\n'
end

File.open playlist_name, 'w' do |f|
  f.write @new
end
```

Answer (score 392, accepted):

Use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes me look like a fool but atleast I now know

Comment: don't be so hard on yourself: the only way to learn is by asking questions.

Comment: @babyrats - u not the only one :)

Comment: i don't know why there should be a difference! i guess '\n' would be string literal

Comment: It seems that both Ruby and PHP do not expand escape sequences in single quoted strings.

Comment: A good way to remember this is that it behaves exactly like string interpolation. "{my_var}" works and '{my_var}' does not work.

Comment: Okay, but why is this necessary?

Comment: @Nuzzolilo Because sometimes you want to output the unescaped form of a string (e.g. because it's already been escaped).

Comment: @mahemoff so double quotes perform escape sequences but single quotes do not?

Comment: "\n" is newline, '\n\ is literally backslash and n.

Comment: 'Single quotes' treat their content literally, which makes them faster and thus recommended wherever possible. "Double quotes" allow for interpolation and escaping of certain characters.

Answer (score 14):

I would like to share my experience with `\n`
I came to notice that "\n" works as-

```
puts "\n\n" // to provide 2 new lines
```

but not

```
p "\n\n"
```

also 
puts `'\n\n'`
Doesn't works.

Hope will work for you!!

Answer (score 12):

You can do this all in the File.open block:

```
Dir.chdir 'C:/Users/name/Music'
music = Dir['C:/Users/name/Music/*.{mp3, MP3}']
puts 'what would you like to call the playlist?'
playlist_name = gets.chomp + '.m3u'

File.open playlist_name, 'w' do |f|
  music.each do |z|
    f.puts z
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess one interesting and useful thing to take away from this is that `puts` outputs a string and an "automatic" trailing line break; that's handier than appending it in code.

Comment: +1 for that and the nice, auto-closing, idiomatic way to process a file.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you don't even need the block:

```
  Dir.chdir 'C:/Users/name/Music'
  music = Dir['C:/Users/name/Music/*.{mp3, MP3}']
  puts 'what would you like to call the playlist?'
  playlist_name = gets.chomp + '.m3u'

  File.open(playlist_name, 'w').puts(music)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it didn't work with adding "\n" to the end of an existing argument to `puts`, so as a workaround I called `print` on the next line with "\n" as an argument, although I suppose I could have just called `puts` again.

This did not produce the desired result:

```
puts "Coach says: #{coach_answer(user_input)}\n"
```

But this did:

```
puts "Coach says: #{coach_answer(user_input)}"
print "\n"
```